# Signature is invalid while calling Saml2PostBinding.Unbind()

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are getting "Signature is invalid" errors while calling `Unbind()` and stumbled upon this in code.
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/42a2d6de46f38d14f0c6f607594d19f2366ad5f2/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Bindings/Saml2PostBinding.cs#L106

Why `validateXmlSignature` argmument is always `true` within `UnbindInternal()`?

```
protected override Saml2Request UnbindInternal(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, string messageName)
{
  UnbindInternal(request, saml2RequestResponse);

  return Read(request, saml2RequestResponse, messageName, true, true);
}
```

Our calling code:

```
 var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(saml2Config);

binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
{   
 throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
}

binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validateXmlSignature` argument is always `true` because the signature is placed in XML in a POST binding and the SAML 2.0 Authn response signature has to be validated. The signature validation is the trust of the SAML 2.0 token.